# Oracle sql date format issue in production and dev

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I had problem of y2k kind.

When I run the below query in both development and production database I get two different results as shown below:

```
Select TO_CHAR(Test_Date,'DD-MM-YYYY') From Test_Table Where row_id = 1;
```

**In Production DB:**

```
TO_CHAR(Test_Date,'DD-MM-YYYY')
-----------------------------------
13-03-2097
```

**In Development DB:**

```
TO_CHAR(Test_Date,'DD-MM-YYYY')
-----------------------------------
13-03-1997
```

The column `Test_Date` is in format of `DD-MM-RR`

Anyone please help with the above discrepancy as I do not know the reason for it.

We are using Oracle 11g.

Comment: Just to let you know, Date is not stored in any format. It is displayed in the console as per the NLS parameters. Check the link here http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14225/ch3globenv.htm#sthref217

Comment: why one is displaying year as 1997 and another one as 2097?

Comment: As said on the first comment you are having trouble with your user session parameters (NLS_PARAMETERS) to be more exact see this doc from oracle: [Date Parameters](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/A84870_01/doc/server.816/a76966/ch2.htm#94690)

Comment: You can be sure in Production DB the date **is** 2097-03-13, and in Development DB it **is** 1997-03-13. Probably it was inserted due to poor default date DD-MM-RR. I am always surprise when people did not learn anything from "Year 2000 Problem"

Comment: The problem is not in data  (most likely due to bad NLS_DATE_FORMAT) you can check it by running the following query select TO_CHAT(sysdate,'DD-MM-YYYY') from dual

Comment: What is datatype of test_date column? If it is DATE, then run `select to_number(test_date - trunc(sysdate)) from test_table where row_id = 1` on both databases to verify that values stored are actually the same. If so then as said before check that NLS_PARAMETERS are consistent on dev and production.

Comment: Are you sure the data is correct?

Answer (score 0):

> In Production DB: 13-03-2097
>   In Development DB: 13-03-1997

This is consistent with using a format mask of `'DD-MM-YY'` in Production and `'DD-MM-RR'` in Development.

With `YY` mask Oracle defaults the century to the current one. The window for RR date format is fixed. Years `00-49` are prefixed with `20` and years `50-99` are prefixed with `19`. No way was `13-03-2097` populated with an `RR` mask.

---

Of course, the real question is why anybody is still using `RR` masks in 2013. It was introduced as a kludge to help organizations avoid the Y2K apocalypse. All new code should enforce four digit years.